# Failed to bind listening port

Tags: relays

I'm having issues with set up of my relay, this is what I got yesterday.....I don't understand how to correct this...

```
Oct 31 08:00:09.000 [notice] Opening OR listener on 0.0.0.0:443
Oct 31 08:00:09.000 [warn] Could not bind to 0.0.0.0:443: Permission denied
Oct 31 08:00:09.000 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
Oct 31 08:00:09.000 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above. For usage, try -h.
Oct 31 08:00:09.000 [warn] Restart failed (config error?). Exiting.
```

Comment: Is something else running on port 443? `sudo lsof -i :443`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [torrc DNSPort 53 - Tor browser will not start / Ubuntu 15](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/8960/torrc-dnsport-53-tor-browser-will-not-start-ubuntu-15)

Comment: Issue looks like it does not have permission to bind to low numbered ports, either start tor as root and use the `User` option to get it to drop privileges after it starts or use a port >1024 (on Linux you can use `setcap` to apply the `cap_net_bind_service` capability to the `tor` binary too)

Comment: This is what I got when running the command in term above:

Comment: how are you launching tor and from what user and on what operating system?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your case is that you're launching Tor process not as a root and trying to bind to a *privileged port*, i.e. the one below 1024. Only root can do such a trick, that's why you're getting permission denied error. It's OK to *launch at startup* as a root, but on the last line of your `torrc` config you **must** drop the root privileges by specifying a line like `User my-tor-unprivileged-user`. Here is how it works: you're starting as a root, *nothing is done* **yet**, so it's 100% safe and you're binding to your ports below 1024. After that, *before* starting to actually operate, Tor switches to another user you're specifying in the last line of your config. So - no traces of root privileges remained, you're limited to your unprivileged user, *but have successfully opened the listeners you require*.

Answer (score 0):

The root error is:

```
Could not bind to 0.0.0.0:443: Permission denied
```

Give permission to the tor binary to listen on ports below 1024 without root access (if you want to listen on 443 for example):

```
sudo setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip /usr/bin/tor
```